# payment-mode=manual - why are we seeing this?

Tags: easy-digital-downloads

We are evaluating EDD on two different development servers, and we have a problem that occurs on one but not the other. The two environments are as identical as we can make them - the only difference we know of is that one server is being used both as server and client (using localhost), and the other is being accessed from a separate machine using a conventional URL.

The error we are seeing (on the server with the full URL) is that the purchase confirmation page has the message:

"Sorry, trouble retrieving payment receipt."

In debugging, we've found that this error is being caused by $session['purchase_key'] being null.

When we hit the Download button that takes us to the purchase confirmation page, we see this URL:

http://our-internal-server-name/store/checkout/?payment-mode=manual

...and then our server hangs.

On the other machine, we see the URL:

http://localhost/store/checkout/

(without ?payment-mode=manual), and it works as intended, and $session['purchase_key'] has a valid value.

We believe that our session data is disappearing on the problem server, but we don't understand why, or where to look to debug this. We do know that the user is logged in when this happens.

Can anyone offer some guidance on what we should be looking at to debug this issue?

Thanks!